# How do I make a StringGrid's columns fit the grid's width?

Tags: delphi, grid, width, stretch

I've been looking for a long time for a solution without any luck. Does anyone know a simple way to do that? I would like to stretch for example the second colum of my grid to fit the grid's width!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `ColWidths` property, like so:

```
with StringGrid1 do
  ColWidths[1] := ClientWidth - ColWidths[0] - 2 * GridLineWidth;
```

And for a more robust and flexible solution, take all fixed columns into account and parameterize the column index:

```
procedure SetColumnFullWidth(Grid: TStringGrid; ACol: Integer);
var
  I: Integer;
  FixedWidth: Integer;
begin
  with Grid do
    if ACol >= FixedCols then
    begin
      FixedWidth := 0;
      for I := 0 to FixedCols - 1 do
        Inc(FixedWidth, ColWidths[I] + GridLineWidth);
      ColWidths[ACol] := ClientWidth - FixedWidth - GridLineWidth;
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetColumnFullWidth(StringGrid1, 4);
end;
```

Comment: Thank you!! this is how it works for me:
`code
procedure SetColumnFullWidth(Grid: TStringGrid; ACol: Integer);
var
  I: Integer;
  FixedWidth: Integer;
begin
  FixedWidth := 0;
  for I := 0 to Grid.ColCount - 1 do begin
    if(I=0) then begin Grid.ColWidths[I] := 50; FixedWidth := FixedWidth +50; end
    else begin Grid.ColWidths[I] := 100; FixedWidth := FixedWidth +100; end;
  end;

  Grid.ColWidths[ACol] := (Grid.Width-FixedWidth)+90;
end;
`code

Answer (score 2):

The following code works with `FixedCols = 0` (to adapt for other values, ex: `FixedCols = 1 ==> for Col := 1 to ...`)

```
procedure AutoSizeGridColumns(Grid: TStringGrid);
const
  MIN_COL_WIDTH = 15;
var
  Col : Integer;
  ColWidth, CellWidth: Integer;
  Row: Integer;
begin
  Grid.Canvas.Font.Assign(Grid.Font);
  for Col := 0 to Grid.ColCount -1 do
  begin
    ColWidth := Grid.Canvas.TextWidth(Grid.Cells[Col, 0]);
    for Row := 0 to Grid.RowCount - 1 do 
    begin
      CellWidth := Grid.Canvas.TextWidth(Grid.Cells[Col, Row]);
      if CellWidth > ColWidth then
        Grid.ColWidths[Col] := CellWidth + MIN_COL_WIDTH
      else
        Grid.ColWidths[Col] := ColWidth + MIN_COL_WIDTH;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

> even better like this :

```
procedure AutoSizeGridColumns(Grid: TStringGrid);
const
  MIN_COL_WIDTH = 15;
var
  Col : Integer;
  ColWidth, CellWidth: Integer;
  Row: Integer;
begin
  Grid.Canvas.Font.Assign(Grid.Font);
  for Col := 0 to Grid.ColCount -1 do
  begin
    ColWidth := Grid.Canvas.TextWidth(Grid.Cells[Col, 0]);
    for Row := 0 to Grid.RowCount - 1 do 
    begin
      CellWidth := Grid.Canvas.TextWidth(Grid.Cells[Col, Row]);
      if CellWidth > ColWidth then
        ColWidth := CellWidth
    end;
    Grid.ColWidths[Col] := ColWidth + MIN_COL_WIDTH;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution If there are more doubts
command "**grid.AutoFitColumns()**"
Where grid is one "TAdvStringGrid";

;)

Answer (score 0):

Allows you to dynamically resize columns depending on the size of the container, given the dimensions of the content.

Call AutoSizeGridColumns when resizing occurs and pass it a TStringGrid object

```
    procedure AutoSizeGridColumns(Grid: TStringGrid);
    var
      ACol, ARow: Integer;
      GridWidth, ColWidth, ColsCount: Integer;
      ColWidthDifferenceWidth, ColMinWidth, ColsSumWidth: Integer;
    begin
      GridWidth := Grid.Width;
      ColsCount := Grid.ColCount;      
      ColWidth := 0;
      ColsSumWidth := 0;
      ColWidthDifferenceWidth := 0;
    
      Grid.Canvas.Font.Assign(Grid.Font);
      for ACol := 0 to ColsCount - 1 do
      begin
    
        for ARow := 0 to Grid.RowCount - 1 do
        begin
          ColMinWidth := Grid.Canvas.TextWidth(Grid.Cells[ACol, ARow]);
        end;
    
        ColsSumWidth := ColsSumWidth + ColMinWidth;
        Grid.ColWidths[ACol] := ColMinWidth;
      end;
           
      if ColsSumWidth < GridWidth then
        begin
          ColWidthDifferenceWidth := (GridWidth - ColsSumWidth) div ColsCount - 1;
    
          for ACol := 0 to ColsCount - 1 do
          begin
            Grid.ColWidths[ACol] := Grid.ColWidths[ACol] + ColWidthDifferenceWidth;
          end;
        end
      else
        begin
          ColWidthDifferenceWidth := (ColsSumWidth - GridWidth) div ColsCount;
    
          for ACol := 0 to ColsCount - 1 do
          begin
            Grid.ColWidths[ACol] := Grid.ColWidths[ACol] - ColWidthDifferenceWidth;
          end;
        end;
    end;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).