# Resize the columns stringgrid in delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8, stringgrid

I want a Stringgrid. I change the size of the columns.

This Stringgrid  is connected to the database. However, I tried different methods; the column did not change. What should I do?

Comment: I doubt that you have a TStringGrid connected to your database - it is a not a data-aware control

Comment: Stringgrid through Live Bindings connected to the database. Except coding, is another way to change the length of the column?

Comment: "*length* of the column" Maybe you mean width?

Comment: I mean width is yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "lengths", i.e. their widths or their heights.

This code will change the lefthand column's width:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SG1.ColWidths[0] := SG1.ColWidths[0] + 10;
end;
```

This link will show you how to "autosize" the grid's column widths:

[How do I make a StringGrid's columns fit the grid's width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884248/how-do-i-make-a-stringgrids-columns-fit-the-grids-width)

In case you actually meant the heights of the cells, you can do this a row at a time like this:

```
procedure TForm1.btnHeightClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SG1.RowHeights[1] := SG1.RowHeights[1] + 10;  //  NB Row 0 is the column header
end;
```

Or, you can set the height of all rows at once like this:

```
procedure TForm1.btnHeightsClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SG1.DefaultRowHeight := SG1.DefaultRowHeight + 10;
end;
```